# how to count dom elements in laravel test

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to count dom elements with laravel test, with css or xpath selectors

I've tried this but getting error below

```
$this->assertCount($number, $this->crawler->filter($selector));

Undefined property: Tests\Feature\PublicUrlsTest::$crawler
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Laravel Dusk for browser testing